# Redirect doesn't work using node.js and ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, ejs

I have spent a lot of time debbuging the following problem but it isn't fixed. The problem occur whenever I the user click on the button and window.locatoin.redirect and window.location.assign methods don't work.

Here is my Code index.ejs:

```
function registration() {
        $.post('/user/register', {
            teamName: $('#teamName').val(),
            faculty: $('#faculty').val(),
            email: $('#emailSignUp').val(),
            password: $('#passwordSignUp').val()
        }).done(
            window.location.assign('/scoreboard')
        )
    }
```

router.js:

```
router.post('/user/register', (req, res) => {
    var newUser = {
        teamName: req.body.teamName,
        faculty: req.body.faculty,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }
    userModel.create(newUser, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('[Registratoin]: ' + err);
        } else {
            console.log('[Registration]: Done');
            req.session.userID = user._id;
            res.redirect('/scoreboard')
        }
    });
})

router.get('/scoreboard', (req, res) => {
    userModel.find({}).sort('-score').exec((err, teams) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('[scoreboard]: ' + err)
        }
        else{
            res.render('main/scoreboard', {
                teamInformation: teams
            }
        )
    }
    })
})
```

When I test the code, I see the `[Registration]: Done` logged correctly. but redirect doesn't work. How should I fix it?

Comment: try using window.location.href instead of   window.location.assign

Comment: @AyeshmanthaPerera Thank you very much for your comment. It still doesn't work, I have changed the method it to  window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/scoreboard';

Comment: window.location.href = "/scoreboard"; is the way

Comment: @AyeshmanthaPerera It still doesn't work properly. The following answer works well. Thank you very very much for your useful answer. I marked your answer as useful :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 introduced the `history.pushState()` and `history.replaceState()` methods, which allow you to add and modify history entries, respectively.

```
history.pushState(null, null, "/scoreboard")
```

More information about the new features of HTML5 to handle these kind of problem are available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

Answer (score 1):

Please using location.href instead of location.assign as below:

```
window.location.href = "/scoreboard";
```

Comment: Did you have used the **pushState** for doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by pushState?

Comment: HTML5 introduced the history.pushState() and history.replaceState() methods, which allow you to add and modify history entries, respectively.
And as I know, you can use the pushState function like the following code to solve your problem(I hope this will be helped you):
`history.pushState(null, null, "/scoreboard")`